# Why aren't these teardrops added to through-hole pads the expected size and shape in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have a through-hole connector which I would like to have teardrops from trace to pad so ensure it is robust and doesn't crack with heat and stress.

[image: Teardrops added to pads and vias]

The teardrops were added to all of these pads using the same settings:

[image: Altium teardrop settings]

However, as is obvious in the picture, the top right pad has a much smaller teardrop. This is even when the option **Force teardrops** is enabled and **Adjust teardrop size** is disabled.

What's going on here?

<sup>*This is in Altium Designer 22.7.1*</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altium appears to not create teardrops very well with non-circular pads. If you inspect the pads, you may find that they are not perfectly circular:

The top pad, shown here, which resulted in an unexpectedly small teardrop is wider than it is tall. Adjust the pad to be equal in width and height, then reapply the teardrop.

[image: Noncircular pad properties]

Comment: This is a good example of a useful self-answered question :)